# Deploying Web-Solutions "deprececated"?

Tags: 2010, 2013, deployment, scope

I am currently in contact with an administrator who has to deploy a feature-solution from another dev.

The solution is deployed globally, which the admin does not like, cause it only is needed for one site collection. So he asked if the dev can change the scope.

His answer was, that this would be technically possible, but is deprecated, cause this would save the application in the IIS-bin of the web application. Deploying it globally instead would save the files inside the 15-hive (which is the one supported). That is why we should deploy globally and hide the feature in the wrong site collections.

Because I never heard of that (or find any clue online): Can someone validate this or in opposite state why this is wrong?

Be aware that I am NOT asking for opinions here, but for prove in form of urls etc.

(I am not in direct contact to the dev so I cannot ask him for more details)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referring to a feature known Code Access Security that was available to Farm solutions under SP2010.

It is not only deprecated, but will also just not work in SP2013.

Here is a good TechNet article on the subject that was created by MVP Margriet Bruggeman and has since been updated by a few people, including some MS staff (you can view the revision history for yourself at the top of the page).

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13373.sharepoint-2013-what-to-do-farm-solution-vs-sandbox-vs-app.aspx

The important bit is in the table toward the bottom:

> [Farm Solution, Server Side Code] Can run full trust code. (Custom CAS policies are not supported in SharePoint 2013. All farm solution code runs in full trust even if it is not deployed to the GAC. Any custom CAS policies are ignored.)

Also worth noting, if you want to use the Sandbox to try to work around this, it is (1) severely limited compared to farm solutions, and (2) also deprecated.